# Is it possible to determine the soundness of the following argument?

Tags: argumentation, validity

I have over-analysed the following question and now find myself thoroughly confused.  I think my issue lies with the use of the word 'some' which we are asked to assume means 'an indeterminate number greater than one' (potentially meaning all).

Is this piece of reasoning sound:

> 1. This piece of reasoning is valid
>      Therefore
> 2. Some pieces of reasoning are valid

Even if the truth of the premise is supposed, it seems to me that the conclusion does not follow *if some means all* ...

Answer (score 1):

*Some* doesn't mean *all*.

It is usually taken to mean *at least one*.

So if I have *some* cards in my hand - I have *at least one*; not *all* and nor *none*.